# Using getElementByID like a document.write()

Tags: javascript, append, getelementbyid

started programming javascript a few months ago. I've been using the 'document.write()' command initially but having it wipe my html each time it's used is a little counterproductive.

Using the getElementByID("div's ID").innerHTML = or anything you think is better, what would effectively run this code but add it to whatever's currently in the div, not replace it.

```
x = x + 1
document.write( "you have clicked this button" + x + "times")
```

So like after 3 clicks it should say:

```
you have clicked this button 1 times
you have clicked this button 2 times
you have clicked this button 3 times
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
```

Where `element` is a reference to a DOM element (e.g. returned from `document.getElementById`).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GGDGA/)

[`insertAdjacentHTML` Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML)

---

**Note:** though `element.innerHTML += htmlString` is also possible, it is usually a bad practice as all of the element's `innerHTML` would be re-parsed into new DOM elements, trashing out the old elements and their attached listeners/data.

Comment: Thanks very much, but where does the div's id go?

Comment: @user2998454 `element` is a reference to an element (e.g. one returned from `document.getElementById`). So `document.getElementById('divId').insertAdjacentHTML(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try console.log(""). the console.log() is used to display your string on the console of your chrome or firefox browser. Right Click on the browser and select inspect element, then select console tab on topright. any errors in the page and any function called on console will be displayed here

Comment: Thanks, but I'm after something that would run in the code itself for the user to activate. Unless I've misunderstood. I'm fairly sure the document.write clears the html by design. I've seen it mentioned in other forums.